# Can't login to Joomla 1.7 admin

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

**UPDATE:**
I checked the prefix_users table in phpMyAdmin and the user I was trying to login with has the `usertype` field set to `deprecated`

I'm running a site on Joomla 1.7, and recently I noticed I can't login to the administrator panel. I'm getting this error:

```
Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.
```

I know the username & password are correct because I checked the `configuration.php` file.
I set permissions to the `configuration.php` file to `0644`, and I've tried setting

```
public $cookie_domain = 'mydomain.com';
public $cookie_path = '';
```

Initially it was `public $cookie_domain = ''`
but that didn't change anything.

I tried both `mydomain.com/administrator` and `www.mydomain.com/adminitrator`

I also tried with a private browsing session in order to avoid any local cookies that might have been stored on my computer in the past.

Note: after a failed login I'm redirected from `mydomain.com/administrator` to `mydomain.com/administrator/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** changed usertype from `deprecated` to `Super Administrator` and then I used this [MD5 hash generator](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php) to update the password.

I think it was because the encryption was wrong...